# Xcode 8 signing errors, can't log in with account and no provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8, provisioning-profile, signing

When I run my application, two errors appear in the Signing part of the General tab of the project. One says, "The operation couldn't be completed. Unable to log in with account ________" while the other says "No profiles for ________ were found." It mentions that Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile. What does this mean, and how do I fix it?

Comment: just must have to give or assign a profile to your app .

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: Check my answer. hope its help you.

Comment: For me, I had two "Teams" one of these teams was for distribution one was for development. The development profile is the only one that worked. Also, make sure your signed in like Geoff Johnson post says.

Comment: This happened to me last Monday. I wasn't at WWDC 2018, but I was working from the Bay Area. I followed the steps in @Geoff Johnson's answer, and saw that my accounts were failing to login with a "403" error. Assuming that was an HTTP status, it means "Forbidden". The problem quietly went away in the afternoon.

Answer (score 115):

I can't take credit for this solution, it came from BrianBatchelder on the apple forum.

I had to go to "XCode" -> "Preferences" -> "Accounts", where it turned out my Apple ID had timed-out. After logging-in there, and then restarting Xcode, my profile was automatically "repaired", and all is now well.

Re-starting Xcode is important there, it doesn't work without it.

Comment: I also found myself timed-out. This fixed it. Seemed to be the (cause? or ) result of a whole string of weird keychain "complaints" from my Mac.

Comment: In Xcode 10.2, this worked for me, and I didn't need to restart Xcode; builds resumed working immediately after I did the step to update my credentials.

Comment: Thanks. This was my problem.

Answer (score 8):

I got around it by unchecking and rechecking:

Project Settings -> General -> Signing -> 'Automatically manage signing'

**IF this not work then try second option:**

I was having this same issue. Here is what I did that solved the problem for me.

1) First I right clicked on each of the two profiles that would "grey-non-download" and moved to trash.

2) Then I deleted the developer account within Xcode.

3) I re-added the developer account, went back to details and download all.

It worked for me, hope this helps.

Comment: What if XCode is unable to add developer account?

Comment: did you restart your Xcode after remove your account @Nij

Comment: Yes, that was sometimes network error and due to this XCode was not able to communicate with apple server.

Comment: I am using Xcode 10.2 and getting this error on a new macOS app that I have started. I looked for Project Settings -> General, but there is no General on that form.

The problem seems to be that they have just introduced 2 factor authentication, and I have a non-email Apple ID used for the developer account.

Comment: @MarkAurelius first of all, you have to authorise your account, then only you can follow second option step/

Comment: OK, Himanshu, what does that involve? I was not aware that it was not authorised. Google is not giving me helpful pages.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you have the right signing identity for :
App : General and Build Settings
AppTests : General and Build Settings

In my case for some reason the AppTests started to have the wrong settings out of nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

This error could happen when XCode is unable to connect to Apple's server.
You can check Apple's system status [here](https://developer.apple.com/system-status/).

Answer (score -1):

In my case, my system date & time was 2 weeks off